# How to prevent blocking path?

Tags: c++

I'm trying build algorithm which prevents to "blocking path". I draw random iteams and print it on the map:
[image]
[image]
[...]
[image]

The "x" is player. It can move on this map, but cannot stay on "#" field. After draw the path is blocked ("x" cannot move to, for example", (3,2):

[image]

Someone have idea, concept or material how to write algorithm which prevent draw "#" when it blocked path?

Here is piece of my code:

```
void build_dungeon(MAP_GRID& map, int chance, string object)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < g_map_size; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < g_map_size; j++){
            if (rand() % 100 >= (100 - chance) && map[i][j] == "[ ]" && anti_stuck(map, i, j)){
                map[i][j] = object;
                print_map(map);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write anti_stuck function.

Comment: Why is your drawing code part of the algorithm?  I would have just expected a 2 dimensional array of int, where each spot in the array denotes a particular state.  You want to draw and compute at the same time, this is a wrong-headed approach.

Comment: If you write about print_map(map) - I put it only for debug.

Comment: But your if() statement contains a very strange looking test for "[ ]".  That's what I'm really referring to.  That shouldn't even be there.  What if next week, you decide to make a GUI game instead of a text game?  Or you choose a different set of characters to write the grid?  The algorithm would stay exactly the same, but the drawing would be different.  Look up `Model-View-Controller` design pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to determine which squares are reachable from a given starting location. See this animation from [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill):

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to determine if you can reach one square from another one, use a [pathfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) algorithm such as [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Again, an animation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm):

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion which can be better? From what does it depend?

Comment: A flood fill will give you **lists** of reachable and unreachable squares. A pathfinding search will just tell you if you can get from A to B. It won't tell you anything about C or D or E.